# Make a row 100% of parent container in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a row to expand to 100% of it's parent height. I've tried with

```
height: 100%;
```

on the row element but it's not working. The parent container also has the `display` property to `flex`. Any idea on how to accomplish this?

This is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqxpwJ

Comment: Try the class `align-self-stretch` on the row.

Comment: It's not working @Klooven

Comment: have you tried `min-height:100%` ?

Comment: Also not working @Jacqueline